# Graphing multiple functions in the same graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am a beginner in latex.

I want to trace 2 functions in latex. These functions are defined by the following array of values:

`X=[-1., -0.35714286 , 0.28571429 , 0.92857143 , 1.57142857 , 2.21428571 , 2.85714286 , 3.5     , 4.14285714 , 4.78571429 , 5.42857143 , 6.07142857 , 6.71428571 , 7.35714286 , 8.]`

`f_1(X)=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

`f_2(X)=[-3.8846153846153846, -3.241758241758242, -2.598901098901099, -1.9560439560439558, -1.3131868131868127, -0.67032967032967, -0.027472527472527056, 0.6153846153846155, 1.2582417582417584, 1.901098901098902, 2.5439560439560447, 3.1868131868131884, 3.82967032967033, 4.472527472527473, 5.115384615384616]`

Here is my try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,xscale=0.6,yscale=0.6]
        \draw[very thinck,->](-2,0)--(10,0) node [right];
             \draw[very thinck,->](0,-20)--(0,100) node [right];
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,...,8} {\draw[very thick] (\x,-0.1cm) -- (\x,0.1cm) node[below] {\x};} 
            \foreach \y in {-10,-8,...,10} {\draw[very thick] (-0.01cm,\y)  -- (0.01cm,\y) node[above] {\y};}
        \draw[smooth,samples=3000,very thick,red] plot coordinates {(-1.0, 1), (-0.3571428571428571, 1), (0.2857142857142858, 1), (0.9285714285714288, 1), (1.5714285714285716, 1), (2.2142857142857144, 1), (2.8571428571428577, 1), (3.5, 1), (4.142857142857143, 1), (4.7857142857142865, 1), (5.428571428571429, 1), (6.071428571428572, 1), (6.714285714285715, 1), (7.357142857142858, 1), (8.0, 1)}; 
        \draw[smooth,samples=3000,very thick,blue] plot coordinates {(-1.0, -3.8846153846153846), (-0.3571428571428571, -3.241758241758242), (0.2857142857142858, -2.598901098901099), (0.9285714285714288, -1.9560439560439558), (1.5714285714285716, -1.3131868131868127), (2.2142857142857144, -0.67032967032967), (2.8571428571428577, -0.027472527472527056), (3.5, 0.6153846153846155), (4.142857142857143, 1.2582417582417584), (4.7857142857142865, 1.901098901098902), (5.428571428571429, 2.5439560439560447), (6.071428571428572, 3.1868131868131884), (6.714285714285715, 3.82967032967033), (7.357142857142858, 4.472527472527473), (8.0, 5.115384615384616)}; 
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But the code does not compile. Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Replace `very thinck` with `very thick` in your code and add at least `{}` to a node, so that it becomes, for example, `\draw[very thick,->] (-2,0) -- (10,0) node [right] {};`. Also, if you use `plot coordinates`, there should not be commas between the single coordinates in the list. And finally, I don't think you want `\draw[very thick,->] (0,-20) -- (0,100) node [right] {};` as this will result in a veeery long vertical line. Try `(0,-20) -- (0,10)` maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the data from your original question (that I still had on disk):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
-1,1,-3.88461538461538,10.8768115942029
-0.35714286,1,-3.24175824175824,6.5664744158533
0.28571429,1,-2.5989010989011,3.08266784974859
0.92857143,1,-1.95604395604396,0.42539189588879
1.57142857,1,-1.31318681318681,-1.40535344572612
2.21428571,1,-0.67032967032967,-2.40956817509613
2.85714286,1,-0.0274725274725271,-2.58725229222123
3.5,1,0.615384615384616,-1.93840579710145
4.14285714,1,1.25824175824176,-0.463028689736763
4.78571429,1,1.9010989010989,1.83887902987282
5.42857143,1,2.54395604395604,4.9673173617273
6.07142857,1,3.18681318681319,8.92228630582669
6.71428571,1,3.82967032967033,13.703785862171
7.35714286,1,4.47252747252747,19.3118160307601
8,1,5.11538461538462,25.7463768115942
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
    \addplot table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, how to name the graph of the function?

Comment: @Karim what do you mean name?

Answer (score 2):

Let's get started with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, very thick] 
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (10,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-9.5) -- (0,10) node[left] {$y$};
        
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,...,9} {
            \ifnum\x=0\else
                \draw (\x,-0.1cm) -- (\x,0.1cm) node[below] {\x};
            \fi
        } 
        \foreach \y in {-9,-8,...,9} {
            \ifnum\y=0\else
                \draw[very thick] (-0.1cm,\y)  -- (0.1cm,\y) node[left] {\y};
            \fi
        }
        
        \draw[smooth, samples=100, very thick, red] plot coordinates {
            (-1.0, 1) 
            (-0.3571428571428571, 1) 
            (0.2857142857142858, 1) 
            (0.9285714285714288, 1) 
            (1.5714285714285716, 1) 
            (2.2142857142857144, 1) 
            (2.8571428571428577, 1) 
            (3.5, 1) 
            (4.142857142857143, 1) 
            (4.7857142857142865, 1) 
            (5.428571428571429, 1) 
            (6.071428571428572, 1) 
            (6.714285714285715, 1) 
            (7.357142857142858, 1) 
            (8.0, 1)
        }; 
        \draw[smooth, samples=100, blue] plot coordinates {
            (-1.0, -3.8846153846153846) 
            (-0.3571428571428571, -3.241758241758242) 
            (0.2857142857142858, -2.598901098901099) 
            (0.9285714285714288, -1.9560439560439558) 
            (1.5714285714285716, -1.3131868131868127) 
            (2.2142857142857144, -0.67032967032967) 
            (2.8571428571428577, -0.027472527472527056) 
            (3.5, 0.6153846153846155) 
            (4.142857142857143, 1.2582417582417584) 
            (4.7857142857142865, 1.901098901098902) 
            (5.428571428571429, 2.5439560439560447) 
            (6.071428571428572, 3.1868131868131884) 
            (6.714285714285715, 3.82967032967033) 
            (7.357142857142858, 4.472527472527473) 
            (8.0, 5.115384615384616)
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

- Setting `scale=0.6` is equivalent to setting `xscale=0.6, yscale=0.6`
- If you want to use `very thick` everywhere, consider setting it as option to the `tikzpicture`. And it is of course `very thick`, not `very thinck`.
- A node needs some contents, even if the contents are empty. So, you need to put `{}` after `node` or `\node`.
- `\draw (0,-20) -- (0,100);` will result in a very long line that is probably longer than the paper size. On the other hand, `\draw (-0.01cm,\y)  -- (0.01cm,\y)` will result in a very short line that is hardly visible. I think, you might want to change the dimensions here.
- When using `plot coordinates`, there should not be commas between the single coordinates in the list. In this case here, I wonder whether it makes sense to draw a line using multiple coordinates that all have the same *y* value ... but I guess, you want to do something differently with this approach.
- It might not be necessary to set `samples=3000`. Try a smaller value first.

Comment: How can I modify the dimensions of \y so that the step is equal for example 2

Comment: @Karim Since the default unit in Ti*k*Z is 1cm, you can add `y=2cm` to the options of `tikzpicture` or use different values for `xscale` and `yscale`. Or do you only want to modify the plot? Then add `y=2cm` or `yscale=2` as option to the `\draw` command ... But note that for more complex graphs, PGFPlots would be the better choice (see the other answer by daleif).

Answer (score 2):

- for your graph I would use `pgfplots` package
- style of graphs than can be determined by `axis` options,
- function coordinates I would collect in table as @daleif do in his minimalistic answer (+1),
- thick lines I would use only for functions:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
-1,             1, -3.88461538461538
-0.35714286,    1, -3.24175824175824
 0.28571429,    1, -2.59890109890110
 0.92857143,    1, -1.95604395604396 
 1.57142857,    1, -1.31318681318681 
 2.21428571,    1, -0.67032967032967 
 2.85714286,    1, -0.02747252747252 
 3.5,           1,  0.61538461538461 
 4.14285714,    1,  1.25824175824176 
 4.78571429,    1,  1.90109890109890 
 5.42857143,    1,  2.54395604395604 
 6.07142857,    1,  3.18681318681319 
 6.71428571,    1,  3.82967032967033 
 7.35714286,    1,  4.47252747252747 
 8,             1,  5.11538461538462 
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-1.5,  xmax=8.5,
ymin=-4.5,  ymax=5.5,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
                ]
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- since graph present two linear function, you can draw them  as straight line between first and last coordinates:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
-1,             1, -3.88461538461538
 8,             1,  5.11538461538462 
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-1.5,  xmax=8.5,
ymin=-4.5,  ymax=5.5,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=2,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
                ]
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.