# The graphical representation to not zigzag

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I tried to compile the following code to draw graphs of some functions defined by an array of values.

**The code is as follows**

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
-1,             1, -3.88461538461538,10.8768115942029,-49.37372620793093, 175.3383368168327, 
-0.35714286,    1, -3.24175824175824,6.566474415853299,-23.612493710583458, 55.10682373726086, 
 0.28571429,    1, -2.59890109890110,3.082667849748595, -6.732218933226122, -2.520938957827919, 
 0.92857143,    1, -1.95604395604396,0.4253918958887899, 2.8611214477562354, -19.7847951798583, 
 1.57142857,    1, -1.31318681318681,-1.4053534457261168,6.761550755978779, -14.825671722387444, 
 2.21428571,    1, -0.67032967032967,-2.409568175096126, 6.563092315056663, -1.6855782611049153, 
 2.85714286,    1, -0.02747252747252,-2.5872522922212347, 3.859769448605049, 9.692392646167214, 
 3.5,           1,  0.61538461538461, -1.9384057971014481, 0.24560548023911766, 13.464065559474449, 
 4.14285714,    1,  1.25824175824176, -0.4630286897367631, -2.6853762664260006, 7.884182156729922, 
 4.78571429,    1,  1.90109890109890, 1.838879029872821, -3.339152467775138, -4.693598766285728, 
 5.42857143,    1,  2.54395604395604, 4.967317361727301, -0.12169980019311577, -17.8167012959243, 
 6.07142857,    1,  3.18681318681319, 8.922286305826688, 8.561005059935194, -20.933632400670078,
 6.71428571,    1,  3.82967032967033, 13.703785862170964, 24.302985436225047,  0.606018068859953, 
 7.35714286,    1,  4.47252747252747, 19.31181603076014, 48.698264652291485, 65.55157737991703, 
 8,             1,  5.11538461538462, 25.746376811594203,83.34086603174967 ,196.75128991761915,

 
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-1.5,  xmax=8.5,
ymin=-50,  ymax=190,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=20,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
                ]
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=4] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=5] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**the result:**

[image]

I want the graphical representation to not zigzag. An idea please.

Comment: Do you have the function that created the data?  One option would be to plot that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It seems that code in your question is based on my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703830)  to your previous question, but you not accepted it nor upvote ... It would be nice and fair, if you do this now.
- Number of samples is to small that functions curves would appear more smooth, that it become, you need to interpolate their values between given samples.
- This can be dan by macro `smooth` which by use of the spline function interpolate function between given samples.
- Macro `smooth` you can add to axis option:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
-1,             1, -3.88461538461538,   10.8768115942029,   -49.37372620793093,     175.3383368168327,
-0.35714286,    1, -3.24175824175824,    6.566474415853299, -23.612493710583458,     55.10682373726086,
 0.28571429,    1, -2.59890109890110,    3.082667849748595,  -6.732218933226122,     -2.520938957827919,
 0.92857143,    1, -1.95604395604396,    0.4253918958887899,  2.8611214477562354,   -19.7847951798583,
 1.57142857,    1, -1.31318681318681,   -1.4053534457261168,  6.761550755978779,    -14.825671722387444,
 2.21428571,    1, -0.67032967032967,   -2.409568175096126,   6.563092315056663,     -1.6855782611049153,
 2.85714286,    1, -0.02747252747252,   -2.5872522922212347,  3.859769448605049,      9.692392646167214,
 3.5,           1,  0.61538461538461,   -1.9384057971014481,  0.24560548023911766,   13.464065559474449,
 4.14285714,    1,  1.25824175824176,   -0.4630286897367631, -2.6853762664260006,     7.884182156729922,
 4.78571429,    1,  1.90109890109890,    1.838879029872821,  -3.339152467775138,     -4.693598766285728,
 5.42857143,    1,  2.54395604395604,    4.967317361727301,  -0.12169980019311577,  -17.8167012959243,
 6.07142857,    1,  3.18681318681319,    8.922286305826688,   8.561005059935194,    -20.933632400670078,
 6.71428571,    1,  3.82967032967033,   13.703785862170964,  24.302985436225047,      0.606018068859953,
 7.35714286,    1,  4.47252747252747,   19.31181603076014,  48.698264652291485,      65.55157737991703,
 8,             1,  5.11538461538462,   25.746376811594203, 83.34086603174967,      196.75128991761915,
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-1.5,  xmax=8.5,
ymin=-50,  ymax=190,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=20,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, samples=15, smooth,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
                ]
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=3] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=4] {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=5] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
However better and more accurate result you will get if for drawing would use functions (as suggested @Teepeemm in his comment), from where are calculated values collected in table.  In this case you can define far more samples, for example 101 or even more and not use `smooth` macro anymore.

For example, that your fifth function in above MWE is defined by:

```
(x-3.5)^4-12*(x-3.5)^2+12
```

(my approximation, you should use one, from which are calculates samples collected in table) than MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
xmin=-1.5,  xmax=8.5,
ymin=-50,  ymax=190,
axis on top,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=20,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1pt, fill=white},
no marks, 
domain=-1:8, samples=101,                % domain and samples, no smooth macro
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick}
                ]
\addplot    {(x-3.5)^4-12*(x-3.5)^2+12}; % my approximation of your function
                                         % you should insert here your formula
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and result is:

[image]

Similarly you can draw other function. Just use their math expressions in `\addplot` instruction.

Comment: Sir, how to name the graph of the function?

Comment: @Karim, you can named function whatever you wish. Also you can write function directly in `addplot` macro as I do in  the second example in answer. BTW, you still not five any credits for using my code in question ...